# Does GeneXus follow the model view controller design pattern for the generated applications

Tags: model-view-controller, genexus

I ask merely to understand and know where to look if I need some back end logic changes, that I have done in let's say Spring.

Specifically is there a 'Middleware' layer in GeneXus like there is in Django?  If I wanted to do some processing for any request flowing through the system, whether it exists today or I add a new transtion tomorrow.

Just trying to understand the internals.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. You kind of have a "view" and a "model", but no controller. You can put some "Controller" logic on procedures, but that's no Middleware

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?16676,MVC+con+GeneXus+-+Una+experiencia+personal,
(in spanish)